# Jquery animation on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've already looked at a few answered questions and none of them worked.
I am trying to make my logo rotate and translate from off the page when the page loads. I am rotating with css but using .animate to translate it. I can't find anything that makes my code work

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9s66oyd4/)

```
<div class="logo">
        </div>


        <div class="info">

        </div>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.logo').animate(
        {left: '200px'}, 2000
        );
    });
    </body>

body {
    background-image: url('images/floor.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info {
    background-color: #966f33;
    width: 12%;
    margin-left: 64%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -208px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 35px 10px #000;
}

.logo {
    background-image: url('images/logo.png');
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -220px;
    animation: rotate 2s linear once;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(720deg);} 
}
```

Comment: You fiddle doesn't have jQuery included.  Click on the gear icon in the script window and select a jQuery version to load.

Comment: Even with the jquery loaded it isnt working https://jsfiddle.net/9s66oyd4/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just animate marginLeft instead of left with jQuery. Your div has position relative.

```
$(function() {
  $('.logo').animate({
    marginLeft: '200px'
  }, 2000);
});
```

I also changed the picture URL in the Fiddle so it can display something.

Here it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/9s66oyd4/2/

Comment: Thanks this works. I had the wrong link to jQuery in my head too.